# Verify that a root lies between two numbers

Tags: numerical-methods

The equation $tanx = \pi - x$ has one root in the interval $0 < x < \frac {1}{2}\pi$. Verify by calculation that this root lies between $1$ and $1.3$.

Comment: Since you are to "verify by calculation" what have you calculated?

Comment: Nothing, it says verify by calculation that this root lies between 11 and 1.31.3.

Comment: What @EthanBolker means is that usually when you ask a question, you should also mention what you have tried and where you got stuck, or what you don't understand, rather than just giving the question with no thoughts of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your equation to have a root, this means that $\tan x-\pi+x=0$ at some $x$. Let $f(x)=x-\pi+\tan x$. Then the root $x_0$ has the property that $f(x_0)=0$. So you just need to show that this is the case for some $x$. To find this is quite hard, but you can show it lies between two points by showing $f(x)>0$ on once side, and $f(x)<0$ on the other side. Here is an example as to why this method works (it assumes you have a continuous function, which you do).

If $f(x)>0$ at some point, say $2$, and $f(x)<0$ at another point, say $0$, then since it is continuous, when going from $0$ to $2$, it must have crossed over from negative to positive, meaning it was zero at some point. This is the method you need to use. Here is a graph to demonstrate this.

[image]

So for your question you must compute $f(1)$ and $1(1.3)$, and if one of these is negative, and the other is positive, then you have verifies the result.

Answer (score 0):

Even though we are asked to do the check "by calculation", we can avoid using a calculator:
Consider the function given by $f(x)=\tan x-(\pi-x)$, which is continuous on $[0,\frac\pi 2)$.

**(A)** From $\pi>3$, we conclude $\tan 1<\tan\frac\pi3=\sqrt 3<2<\pi-1$. Thus $f(1)<0$.

**(B)** As $\tan$ is increasing in the interval of interest and $\pi<3.15$, we have $1.3>\frac \pi3+0.25$.
If we let $\alpha=\arctan 0.25$, then clearly $0<\alpha<0.25$, so $1.3>\frac\pi3+\alpha$ and from the addition theorem,
$$\tan1.3>\frac{\tan\frac\pi3+\tan\alpha}{1-\tan\frac\pi3\tan\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt 3+\frac14}{1-\frac14\sqrt3}$$
As $\sqrt 3>\frac76 $, we find  $\sqrt 3+\frac14 > 2-\frac12\sqrt 3$ and so $\tan1.3>2$. With $\pi-1.3<2$, this tells us $f(1.3)>0$.

By the IVT, $f$ has a root between $1$ and $1.3$.